# TimerTask executing on unequal time intervals

Tags: android, android-asynctask, oncreate, timertask

I've been working on looping AsyncTask on Android. I used an idea suggested by one of user and I came up with this:

```
public void loopAsyncTaskGetter(){
    final Handler handler = new Handler();
    final Timer timer = new Timer();
    TimerTask doAsynchronousTask = new TimerTask() {       

        @Override
        public void run() {         
                handler.post(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {       
                        try {                                                               
                            new GetTasksAsync().execute(getIntent().getStringExtra(MainActivity.EXTRA_ID));                        
                        } catch (Exception e) {

                        }
                    }
                });
            }           
    };      
    timer.schedule(doAsynchronousTask, 500, 1000*30); 

}
```

My AsyncTask extending class looks like that:

```
class GetTasksAsync extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Void>{
    ProgressDialog dialog;
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute(){
        //dialog stuff
        super.onPreExecute();
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(String... data) {
                    //this method below returns JSON String from my PHP file
        String jsonData = Webserv.getTaskJson(data[0]);

        try {
            JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(jsonData);

            for(int i=0; i<jsonArray.length(); i++){
                //some json parsing, doesn't matter                 
            }


        } catch (JSONException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


        return null;
    }
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void v){
        dialog.dismiss();           
        myAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();   
        super.onPostExecute(v);
    }
```

I call loopAsyncTaskGetter() on my onCreate() method of Activity and I expect to have things done once for 30 seconds, and again. The strange thing for me is, that sometimes it works once for 30 seconds, and sometimes it gets done f.e. 3 times in 5 seconds, like much more often. Could anybody tell me why it works this way? Where did I make a mistake?

Kind regards!

Answer (score 0):

You don't cancel your Timer when you're done with it. And because of that, you probably have multiple timers running in the background. Pass your Timer as a parameter to your asynctask and cancel it in onPostExecute.

Comment: Well, but if I cancel my timer, it's not gonna work in loop. I just did it, for curiousity, it got executed only once, as I expected :( But thanks for reply!

Comment: how many times do you call loopAsyncTaskGetter() method? if you call it only once, then the problem is your async task sometimes takes longer, so sometimes you make a new asynctask call before the previous one ends. And because of that, you see multiple updates in a short period of time.

Comment: Yea, I call it only once, @ onCreate() method. One execution lasts like a second or something, so I think it's not possible

Comment: can you share your onCreate method, and the part where you call loopAsyncTaskGetter?

Comment: By the way, I'm doing another AsyncTask after noticing changes in location. May it cause a problem? I read somewhere that there's a number of AsyncTasks that can be executed paralelly. My android version is 2.3.4. I'm still stuck at this point. I'd like it to work as I want

Comment: It's fine with your version, but with versions>honeycomb, you'll have issues with parallel async tasks.